# Знак доллара перед именем свойства в self

Tags: php

Почему после `::` идет знак `$`, и в каких случаях это бывает?

```
self::$classes
```

почему не `self::classes`? В `parent::` бывает так же?

Answer (score 3):

`self::$classes` - обращение к статическим свойствам (переменным) внутри класса;

`self::classes()` - обращение к статическим методам внутри класса;

`self::CLASSES` - обращение к константам внутри класса.

> в parent:: бывает так же?

аналогично.

Про динамический доступ к статическим методам написал [[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks).

Comment: круто, не знал/не использовал никогда в отношении констант класса. Начиная с каких версий php это поддерживается?

Comment: Вместо self::CLASSES предпочитаю static::CLASSES, т.к. используя в методе базового класса self::CLASSES будем во всех производных классах получать одно и то же значение - константу базового класса.

Используя static::CLASSES в методе базового класса (и переопределив константу в производном) - будет использовано значение константы производного класса

Comment: @sergiks:

Константы бывают разные:

 - неограниченной областью видимости
   (`define`) - инициализирующий
   вначале, а потому, доступны везде
   независимо от места их объявления;


 - с ограниченной (`const`) - должны
   быть объявлены в самой верхней
   области видимости. Их нельзя
   объявлять внутри функций, циклов или
   выражений if. Кроме того, нельзя
   присвоить им значения переменных и
   совершать иные операции (к примеру,
   побитовые операции) - указывать явное
   значение.  Работают быстрее и памяти
   потребляют меньше. С PHP 5.3 доступны
   и вне классов.

Answer (score 2):

См. пример №3 в [документации про Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Переменная `$classes` содержит в себе строку, имя статического свойства или метода:

```
$classes = 'frukt';
$var = self::$classes; // то же, что $var = self::frukt;

// может также быть имя метода:
$classes = 'kotory_chas';
self::$classes(); // то же, что self::kotory_chas();
```